# ValidationError: "tenantId" is not allowed when using AzureAD for hapi JS route authorization

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, hapi.js

We are trying to use @hapi/bell on our back-end routes to provide authorization. The authentication strategy uses `azure` as provider and the scheme is `bell`

This is how I register the strategy. The `clientId`, `clientSecret`, `tenantId` and `password` are hidden for obvious reasons

`server.auth.strategy('azureAD', 'bell', {
    provider: 'azure',
    clientId: '...',
    clientSecret: '...',
    tenantId: '...',
    password: '...',
    providerParams: {
      response_type: 'code'
    },
    scope: ['openid', 'offline_access', 'profile', 'User.Read']
  })`

When I run the server, I get the following error:

`{ [ValidationError: "tenantId" is not allowed] ...`

Now, looking into the azure portal, we definitely want to be supporting accounts only inside the organisation i.e. single-tenant.

If I remove the `tenantId` option and restart the server I get CORS error which essentially says that our app is not configured as a multi-tenant application and we need to use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant. Adding the `tenantId`, however, says that it is not allowed.

Any guidance as to why this is happening will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Im not familiar with hapijs, but I am with js itself and they are considered public applications. This means that client secret is not required (because it will be exposed to the world opening a HUGE door for hackers). Maybe [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-initializing-client-applications) could help you.

Comment: "on our back-end routes" it's a confidential client.

Comment: @TiagoBrenck If I remove the client secret, the server doesn't run and throws an error stating that client secret is required.

Comment: @juunas not entirely sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: I was answering TiagoBrenck's comment that you should not put client secrets in a public client. From what I understood in your question, your code runs in a back-end, and is thus a confidential client, which can use a client secret to authenticate itself.

Comment: @juunas Yes, that is exactly the case

Comment: Oh sorry, I miss understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that instead of registering the strategy as I have shown in the question the following could be done:

```
const custom = Bell.providers.azure({ tenant: '...' })

server.auth.strategy('azureAD', 'bell', {
  provider: custom,
  clientId: '...',
  clientSecret: '...',
  password: '...',
  isSecure: false, // look into this, not a good idea but required if not using HTTPS
  providerParams: {
    response_type: 'code'
  },
  scope: ['openid', 'offline_access', 'profile', 'User.Read']
})
```

This gets rid of the `"tenantId"` is not allowed error, however, we now get a different error stating `Authentication failed due to: Missing custom request token cookie`.

Bell suggests that a common solution is to combine bell with the **hapi-auth-cookie** authentication scheme plugin, so now this is something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

The Joi package is validating the schema and throwing errors.  See config property below.  It overrides options and avoids the "tenantId" or "tenant" is not allowed error you are seeing. Also, in recent versions Bell Azure Provider wants "tenant" not "tenantId" property.

```
server.auth.strategy('azureAD', 'bell', {
  provider: 'azure',
  config: {
    tenant: '...',
    useParamsAuth: false,
  },
  clientId: '...',
  clientSecret: '...',
  password: '...',
  providerParams: {
    response_type: 'code'
  },
  scope: ['openid', 'offline_access', 'profile', 'User.Read'],
  isSecure: false,
})
```